# Is there a function like AVERAGEX but counts instead of averaging the sums?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

I have a function in PowerPivot Excel that gives me the average of the summed rows, and only counts if the sums are 100%.

The reason I do this: For each order coming in on one trailer (load), some of the items were not completely fulfilled, therefore "Is On Time" is set to 0 instead of 1 for each. I then average the whole load to see the total "on time" percentage.

Formula:
On Time:=AVERAGEX(VALUES('table1'[Loads]), IF(AVERAGE[Is On Time]=1, 1, 0))

Here's an example of what the table in PowerPivot looks like, and what I'd like the output to eventually look like:
[image]

Is there a way to do the same but only count the total instead of averaging it all. I was hoping COUNTX but it doesn't work the same.

Comment: FYI, this KPI seems to work, however I'm not sure how to make it return a 0 if no rows were found:  Loads OT:=COUNTX(VALUES('table1'[Load]), IF([Is On Time]=1, 1, BLANK()))

Answer (score 1):

Something like :

```
{ = MIN( IF( $A$3:$A$11=D3, $B3:B$8 ) ) }
```

Or

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$11;"="&D3;$B$3:$B$11;"=0")>0;1;0)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in PowerPivot kpi?

Comment: I think **=CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(DISTINCT([Column])), conditions of the IF you desire)** is PowerPivot alternative.

Comment: My only challenge is to find a way to plug your formula as a KPI so I can create a pivot in Excel. It seems the CALCULATE function only works in each rows but not KPI

Answer (score 0):

This KPI seems to work. (Is On Time is a KPI to give me the average of the column, which is usually 1s or 0s)

```
Loads OT:=COUNTX(VALUES('table1'[Load]), IF([Is On Time]=1, 1, BLANK()))
```

The only issue I have is it returns BLANK if no rows were counted. Is there a way to make it return a 0?

Comment: Add a "+0" to the end to handle the blank case.